# Rails install suddenly requires concurrent-ruby gem and fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, macos-mojave, concurrent-ruby

After a system upgrade to macOS 10.14 I am suddenly unable to install Rails 3.2.5 on Ruby 1.8.7, since a new gem is required now: Concurrent-ruby.

I was able to install and use this system on macOS 10.13. Why is concurrent-ruby suddenly a requirement? How can I find a way to get on without it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

I used to install some gems before installing Rails 3.
These were:

```
rdoc-data -v 3.12
i18n -v 0.6.11
execjs -v 1.4.0 
rack-cache -v 1.2
rails -v 3.2.5
```

I found out that I had to install

```
rack -v 1.4.7
```

before installing

```
rack-cache -v 1.2
```

Now I am again able to install Rails 3.

Somehow the install process must have loaded the requirements for a newer version of i18n, since later versions of this gem require concurrent-ruby.

Answer (score -1):

Rails 3.2.5 on Ruby 1.8.7? Do you need that old versions?

Comment: Please add this as a comment rather than an answer. Questions aren't answers.

Comment: Unfortunately yes. The production environment does not allow anything above 1.8.7 and development environment was working until macOS 10.13.

Comment: @CarlMarkham I'm kind of new here. I didn't know about the comments / answers. I will keep it in mind. Thanks. By the way I need 50 reputation in order to add a comment.